# I cannot change my textView text in visual studio 2015 (Android)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, android-edittext, textview

I am very new to Visual Studio. I'm required to create an android app with Visual Studio. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Currently I have an android project with 2 activities (details and confirmation). In the details page, there are EditText for the user to input the details and in the confirmation page, a TextView is used to show the user input.

I have done this 2 activities, but when I run it, the confirmation page will be empty. I'm not sure whether my code is right or not.

There are few problems I encounter right now :-

- how to get the EditText value and **assign** it to variable
- how to **pass** the value from one activity to another
- how to **read** the value that is passed from the other activity
- how to **change** the TextView text

> details.xml

```
<EditText
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:id="@+id/jobNumber"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:id="@+id/statusCode"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:id="@+id/statusDescription"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:id="@+id/remarks"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

> Details.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.DetailsPage);

    EditText jn = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.jobNumber);
    EditText sc = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.statusCode);
    EditText sd = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.statusDescription);
    EditText r = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.remarks);

    String jobNum = jn.Text;
    String statusC = sc.Text;
    String statusD = sd.Text;
    String remarks = r.Text;

    Button next = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.next);

    next.Click += delegate
    {
        Intent act = new Intent(this, typeof(Confirmation));

        act.PutExtra("jNum", jobNum);
        act.PutExtra("SC", statusC);
        act.PutExtra("SD", statusD);
        act.PutExtra("R", remarks);

        StartActivity(act);
    };
}
```

> confirmation.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"    
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView7" />
<TextView
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView8" />
<TextView
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView9" />
<TextView
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView10" />
```

> Confirmation.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Confirmation);

    String jobNumber = Intent.GetStringExtra("jNum");
    String statusCode = Intent.GetStringExtra("SC");
    String statusDescription = Intent.GetStringExtra("SD");
    String remarks = Intent.GetStringExtra("R");

    TextView jn = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView7b;
    TextView sc = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView8);
    TextView sd = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView9);
    TextView r = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView10);

    jn.Text = jobNumber;
    sc.Text = statusCode;
    sd.Text = statusDescription;
    r.Text = remarks;
}
```

Please help me, what do I do wrong? **Why the TextView text does not change.** Thank you so much in advance for those who try and solve this problem for me. APPRECIATE IT!

Regards,
Azizi

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No error, but the TextView is empty. I can't view the any text in the TextView

Comment: @amitairos I just don't know what is wrong. Is my code correct? Or is there any error somewhere? I've tried to search it online, but I couldn't found anything that can resolves my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint where you call GetStringExtra and see if you get the string. That will help as a start.

Comment: Also, please post your full code of everything.

Comment: @amitairos Thank you for your effort to help me. But I just found the solution in youtube. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtLac9HpHSw) This video does what I wanted and it works like charm. Anyway, thank you so much for your time and effort. Appreciate it a lot.Thanks man!

Comment: Do you know what the problem was? It would be nice if you put that as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to edit the Text variable directly, that is not possible. Use getText() and setText() instead.

For example:

Get text

`String jobNum = jn.getText()`;

Set text

`jn.setText(jobNumber)`

Comment: He's using Xamarin, in which what he did is acceptable.

Comment: @Aenadon Thank you for your reply. But it is an error for me when I use getText() and setText()

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are taken the texts when the Details activity starts, and obviously the text boxes are empty.

Put this:

```
String jobNum = jn.Text;
String statusC = sc.Text;
String statusD = sd.Text;
String remarks = r.Text;
```

Inside the button click delegate method.